# Split col by any delimiter and Uppercase values

Tags: python, pandas, split

I'm trying to split a column by the last `' - '` that is followed by all uppercase strings letters.

Below, I have a df with `Value` containing various combinations. I want to split the col into two individuals columns, whereby, everything before the last `' - '` and uppercase letters.

I've got `Last` column correct but not `First` column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Value': [
        'Juan-Diva - HOLLS',
        'Carlos - George - ESTE BAN - BOM',
        'Javier Plain - Hotham Ham - ALPINE',
        'Yul - KONJ KOL MON'],
   })
```

option 1)

```
df[['First', 'l']] = df['Value'].str.split(' - ', n=1, expand=True)

df['Last'] = df['Value'].str.split('- ').str[-1]
```

option 2)

```
# Regular expression pattern
pattern = r'^(.*) - ([A-Z\s]+)$'

# Extract groups into two new columns
df[['First', 'Last']] = df['Value'].str.extract(pattern)
```

option 3)

```
df[["First", "Last"]] = df["Value"].str.rsplit(" - ", n=1, expand=True)
```

Option 4 works but is incredibly slow. Use case datasets are only a few hundred rows and it's still computing after hours.

Option 4)

```
df[["First", "Last"]] = df["Value"].str.extract(r'(.*?)\s*-\s*([A-Z]+(?:\s*-?\s*[A-Z]+)*)')
```

intended output:

```
                       First            Last
0                  Juan-Diva           HOLLS
1            Carlos - George  ESTE BAN - BOM
2  Javier Plain - Hotham Ham          ALPINE
3                        Yul    KONJ KOL MON
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you have?

Comment: *"and where all string letters are uppercase"* - Is that significant? In this data it's not, and your code doesn't handle it, so I suppose you're only mentioning it because it makes it easy to read this data, right?

Comment: It is significant. I need it to handle both. Please see update

Answer (score 2):

**Using Pandas' built-in vectorized string operations**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Value': ['Juan-Diva - HOLLS', 'Carlos - George - ESTE BAN', 'Javier Plain - Hotham Ham - ALPINE', 'Yul - KONJ KOL MON'],
})

# Regular expression pattern
pattern = r'^(.*?) - ([A-Z\s-]+)$'

# Extract groups into two new columns
df[['First', 'Last']] = df['Value'].str.extract(pattern)

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                Value                      First          Last
0                   Juan-Diva - HOLLS                  Juan-Diva         HOLLS
1          Carlos - George - ESTE BAN            Carlos - George      ESTE BAN
2  Javier Plain - Hotham Ham - ALPINE  Javier Plain - Hotham Ham        ALPINE
3                  Yul - KONJ KOL MON                        Yul  KONJ KOL MON
```

In this code, the regular expression `r'^(.*?) - ([A-Z\s-]+)$'` is used with `.str.extract()`. The pattern is designed to split a string into two parts:

1. `^(.*?)` captures the beginning of the string up to the last occurrence of " - ".
2. `([A-Z\s-]+)$` captures the final segment of the string, which must consist only of uppercase letters, spaces, or hyphens.

The pattern ensures the split occurs at the last " - " followed by a sequence of uppercase characters, spaces, or hyphens at the end of the string.

---

**Alternate method using `re` module**

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Value': ['Juan-Diva - HOLLS', 'Carlos - George - ESTE BAN', 'Javier Plain - Hotham Ham - ALPINE', 'Yul - KONJ KOL MON'],
})

# Function to split the string
def split_value(s):
    # Find the last occurrence of ' - ' followed by uppercase letters
    match = re.search(r'^(.*?) - ([A-Z\s-]+)$', s)
    if match:
        return match.group(1), match.group(2)
    else:
        return s, None

# Apply the function to each row in 'Value' column
df[['First', 'Last']] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x: split_value(x)).tolist()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                Value                      First          Last
0                   Juan-Diva - HOLLS                  Juan-Diva         HOLLS
1          Carlos - George - ESTE BAN            Carlos - George      ESTE BAN
2  Javier Plain - Hotham Ham - ALPINE  Javier Plain - Hotham Ham        ALPINE
3                  Yul - KONJ KOL MON                        Yul  KONJ KOL MON
```

I'm using the `re.search` function to find matches according to the specified pattern. The pattern `r'^(.*?) - ([A-Z\s-]+)$'` is the same one I used above. If a match is found, the function returns the two parts of the string; otherwise, it returns the original string and `None` for the 'Last' column. The results are then converted to a list and assigned to the new columns 'First' and 'Last'.

Comment: Can we get the first delimiter and uppercase strings?

Comment: FYI, OP edited the question. Your solution just needs two little tweaks to work: add a hyphen to the second group and make the first group non-greedy: `r'^(.*?) - ([A-Z\s-]+)$'`

Comment: @wjandrea - Updated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you should use `.str.rsplit`:

```py
df[["First", "Last"]] = df["Value"].str.rsplit(" - ", n=1, expand=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                Value                      First          Last
0                   Juan-Diva - HOLLS                  Juan-Diva         HOLLS
1          Carlos - George - ESTE BAN            Carlos - George      ESTE BAN
2  Javier Plain - Hotham Ham - ALPINE  Javier Plain - Hotham Ham        ALPINE
3                  Yul - KONJ KOL MON                        Yul  KONJ KOL MON
```

Comment: Nice. So .rsplit take the last?

Comment: @jonboy Yes, the `r` in `rsplit` means split from the right side.